# Error in magic number when converting pyc python code to py source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, decompiling

I tried to use a tool called easy python decompile and websites to convert pyc python code to source (.py) again, but I have got an error in magic number.

Also, I tried the following commands using command prompt using pycdc.exe:

```
pycdc.exe OSV_Main.pyc
```

I got a little part of my source code and then stopped with the following error:

`Error decompyling OSV_Main.pyc: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 32) >= this->size() (which is 20)`

Please refer to the screenshot of the error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwgMl.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCf9Y.png)

How can I retrieve all the source code as the version of python I used 3.11?

Comment: `BEFORE_WITH` is new in python 3.11 https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BEFORE_WITH it looks like your disassembler has not caught up yet.

Comment: Can you add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error in your screenshots from that disassembler, I see:

> Unsupported opcode: BEFORE_WITH

I also see that you are using python 3.11.

Taking both into account it happens to be the case that this opcode is new in version 3.11

**per:** [Disassembler for Python bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BEFORE_WITH)

and it looks like your disassembler has just not caught up with 3.11 yet.

Comment: How to decompile my code ?

Comment: Not a recommendation, just an observation that this tool claims to support 3.11 [Python Source Code Compile and Decompile Online](https://www.lddgo.net/en/string/pyc-compile-decompile)

Comment: Same, just few lines of the code. Can the source code for pycdc be altered to support version 3.11 of python?

Comment: probably, but I am not familiar with it. I'm sure they would love support.

Comment: Why not use that online tool I posted a link to?

Comment: Where is it? , no tool!.

Comment: Retrived part of the code also.

Comment: Could you fix the source code of pybcd then build in order to be useful for 3.11 python version as I am new to this, and I tried but failed to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try: https://www.lddgo.net/en/string/pyc-compile-decompile

Comment: Not working Mr Jone and actullay I need to solve this big problem for me. Do you have any help ? Can you recive the folder that has all the decomiled files and the PYC code?

Comment: Iddgo.net is built on pycdc and uncompyle6. Both of which do not have full support for all the opcodes introduced in 3.11. You're best making an issue on the pycdc git and waiting for the developers to add support, or pay someone else to add support.